# How to re attach to a xen domain console?

Tags: console, xen

I know one can use "xm co " for attaching to console of an domU. 
My question is how to attach to a console, if the console was already attached by other user/process. 
If i try to attach to console(xm co) which was already attached by other user/process i get garbled output like following
"ceLiu Seve elese 68
                    enl411-021e6kx66 na 8_4

```
                                       v-m oi:
```

"

Thanks in advance for help,
Prad G.

Comment: I know one can use "xm co " for attaching to console of an domU. My question is how to attach to a console, if the console was already attached by other user/process. If i try to attach to console(xm co) which was already attached by other user/process i get garbled output like following "ceLiu Seve elese 68 enl411-021e6kx66 na 8_4

                                       v-m oi:

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get PID,  "ps -ef |grep xenconsole" and kill that process.

```
root     16313 25572  0 Jun26 pts/12   00:00:00 /usr/lib64/xen/bin/xenconsole 1 --num 0
```

Is there any other way ?